# Mysql compare sum of columns to columns in another table

Tags: mysql

How can I select a row from another table based on the sum of column from the left table

```
SELECT Group_concat(c.cartid SEPARATOR ',') AS CartIDs, 
       Sum(c.grandtotal)                    AS Sum, 
       r.percentage 
FROM   carts c 
       LEFT JOIN rebates r 
              ON Sum(c.grandtotal) >= r.fromamountpurchased 
                 AND Sum(c.grandtotal) <= r.toamountpurchased 
WHERE  c.ispaid = '1' 
       AND c.addedtorebates = '0' 
GROUP  BY c.customerid
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried `HAVING` also doesn't work.

Is it possible in one query?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carts` (
  `CartID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `GrandTotal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `IsPaid` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL,
  `AddedToRebates` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CartID`)
)

    INSERT INTO `carts` (`CartID`, `CustomerID`, `GrandTotal`,  `IsPaid`,
    `AddedToRebates`, ) VALUES
    (71, 28,  '57450.00', '1', '0' ),
    (73, 28,  '57450.00', '1', '0');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rebates` (
  `RebateID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Percentage` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'in %',
  `FromAmountPurchased` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `ToAmountPurchased` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `CashEquivalent` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RebateID`)
)



 INSERT INTO `rebates` (`RebateID`, `Percentage`, `FromAmountPurchased`, 
`ToAmountPurchased`, `CashEquivalent`) VALUES
    (1, '5', '50000.00', '69999.00', '3000.00'),
    (2, '10', '70000.00', '79999.00', '5000.00'),
    (3, '15', '80000.00', '89999.00', '6000.00'),
    (4, '20', '90000.00', '99999.00', '7000.00'),
    (5, '25', '100000.00', '150000.00', '8000.00'),
    (6, '0', '0.00', '49999.00', '0.00');
```

Comment: please post your table structures & sample input output.

Comment: Since you're using an alias.  You could use `Sum` instead of `SUM(c.GrandTotal)` but you should probably avoid using the name of a function.

Comment: @Devon it produces an error #1054 Unknown column 'Sum' in 'on clause'

Comment: i'm pretty sure you cant use an aggregate function in a join predicate

Comment: @pala_ looks like i have to separate it in another query

Comment: @basic_space i have done so for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select q1.CartIDs, q1.total, r.percentage
  from
    (select group_concat(c.cartid) as CartIDs, sum(c.grandtotal) as total
      from carts c
        where c.ispaid = '1'
        and c.addedtorebates = '0'
      group by c.customerid ) q1
    left join rebates r
      on q1.total >= r.fromamountpurchased 
        and q1.total <= r.toamountpurchased
```

Here is a demo fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d27f5/3

You cannot use aggregate functions like `SUM()` in the join predicate, so in this instance, a subquery is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result with a sub query.  Please note that this sub query requires an additional scan of carts.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.CartID SEPARATOR ',') AS CartIDs, SUM(c.GrandTotal) as Sum, r.Percentage 
FROM carts c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(GrandTotal) as grandTotal, CustomerID
  FROM carts
  GROUP BY CustomerID
) cSums ON cSums.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN rebates r ON cSums.grandTotal >= r.FromAmountPurchased AND cSums.grandTotal <= r.ToAmountPurchased
WHERE c.IsPaid = '1' AND c.AddedToRebates = '0' GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```